# Get First Vid From Youtube VB.NET

Tags: html, regex, vb.net, youtube

Im trying to get the first youtube link from youtube or google but I can't get it to work. can someone please help me out?

```
Dim m As New Regex("<a href=""/watch?v=.*""")
```

Dim request2 As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + ListBox1.SelectedItem + " " + ListBox2.SelectedItem)

`Dim responseyoutube As System.Net.HttpWebResponse = request2.GetResponse
    TextBox2.Text = (request2.Address.ToString)
    Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(responseyoutube.GetResponseStream())
    Dim rssourcecodey As String = sr.ReadToEnd
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = m.Matches(rssourcecodey)
    TextBox1.Text = rssourcecodey

    For Each itemcode2 As Match In matches
        youtube = itemcode2.Value.Split("=").GetValue(1)

        ListBox2.Items.Add(youtube)`

Comment: What's the output it's giving you at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is a special meta char in regex which makes the previous token as optional one (not the one after `*` or `+`). So you need to escape the `?` symbol in-order to match a literal `?` symbol.

```
Dim m As New Regex("<a href=""/watch[?]v=.*""")
```

OR

```
Dim m As New Regex("<a href=""/watch\\?v=.*""")
```

Comment: Everything is special in regex.

Comment: you may consider using non-greedy at the last `Dim m As New Regex("<a href=""/watch[?]v=.*?""")`